# Targeting a specific image for animation

Tags: html, css

I used CSS flashing property to animate a specific image and there are several sources online in this regard, but none of them are talking on how to target a specific image in the HTML page. I have several images linked in my HTML page and I just want one of the images to blink/flash not all of them. I used below code and now all of my images are blinking. I tried a lot to paste/write my css code here, but it looks like the system is not allowing me because the of the formatting, while I don't see any issue with my code format.

```
@keyframe blink { 0% { opacity: 1; } 50% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } } 
flashing-effect img { animation: blink 1s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
```

Comment: Forgot to include code?

Comment: **I used below code and now all of my images are blinking** Without code, can´t do nothing.

Comment: @keyframe blink {
  0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    }

flashing-effect img {
    animation: blink 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

Comment: @John Did you indent the code/use the code-button from the editor? In any case, I copied the code into the question. Feel free to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a class name to the image you wish to be blinking.

Such as:

```html
<img src="..." class="flashing-image"/>
```

Then, in your CSS, target it appropriately:

```css
.flashing-image {
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
```

Comment: This is my html and css code and its not working for me:       <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="w-73 mx-auto">

        <a href="portfolio/index.html" target="_blank"> <img src="img/Button.png" class="flashing-image"></a>

   </div>
  </div>
</div>       .flashing-image{
   margin-top:380px;
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   animation: blink 1s;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

Comment: You forgot to include your `@keyframes` delcaration. Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbw3dqps/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right, I forgot the @keyframe.